# How can I repeat a Linux command every minute?

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I'd like to get a Linux command which runs in the background and writes something to the terminal screen every one minute. I am trying to keep `ssh` session alive, I am using Cygwin for connection to the server but the connection is resetting every short time if nothing is written to the screen.

I already tried with `sshd_config` option to solve the short connection time by changing `ServerAliveInterval 0` to `ServerAliveInterval 60` but this does not solve the problem.

Comment: I am trying to keep ssh session alive, I am using Cygwin for connection to the server but the connection is resetting every short time if nothing is written to the screen.

Comment: Why do you want to keep your ssh session alive? You can use `nohup` to keep your program running and just `pipe` the output to a file.

Comment: In "It doesn't work", what does "it" refer to? What you tried to change in `sshd_config`? If you want to solve this properly, provide some more detail we might point you to what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Setting `ServerAliveInterval` in the `sshd_config` file is pointless (it's a client-side option). I suggest you re-read the answers in the duplicate question (particularly the accepted answer).

Answer (score 4):

There's `watch`, loops with `sleep`, `crontab`, and many other options:

```
watch -n 60 echo hello world


while :; do echo hello world; sleep 60; done


crontab -e #...
```

Comment: You omitted the trivial solution: Just type in the command every 60 seconds and press "Enter."  ;)

Answer (score 1):

I agree this might be a duplicate of the question linked, but there are times when those options in the `sshd_config` just don't work.

In those situations, I use `tmux` on the target server with a lower status bar which has the time in it, updated every 15 seconds.